# Accessing a LAN resource on WAN?

Tags: lan, remote-control, wan

I realize it is not easy to do, i tried googling a lot but all i end up with is accessing computers. I want to access a different resource, and i don't know how.

The resource lies on a fixed L.A.N IP 192.168.1.9:80. Accessing it when on my LAN would show me some HTML with my security camera.
Problem is, i want to access the same over W.A.N (Access it remotely).

Reading tidbits from my googling and a unlucky guess, i tried to portforward 80 to 192.168.1.9 and accessing it over my pc's public IP, but as you may already know that didn't work. Is there any way for me to access this LAN resource over WAN?

Note: Slight edit. According to the configuration, the HTTP port is 80 and data port 10000, my bad. :/

Comment: What is the *data port* in your configuration?

Comment: To be honest i'm not sure what it is, but for the most part i just want to be able to access the HTTP connection

Comment: Port forwarding should be enough to make it work, but that data port looks suspicious. Where did you find it or where can you set it?

Comment: Well it's in the config, but i am pretty sure it doesn't matter. Although how exactly do i port forward it? It's on the default port 80 and it won't let me change the port, and i don't think forwarding to port 80 is a good idea.

Comment: In *what* config? Please try to provide as many details as possible. Port forwarding can be set up in your router's configuration and depends on router model and firmware. Most basic firmwares require you to enter only port number and local IP. Advanced ones may let you redirect connections to another port, in this case it should be 80 too.

Comment: I mean in the camera's config. I tried to set up a port forward on 80 redirecting to 192.168.1.9, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind having other people see your camera's images, then what you yourself suggested, port forwarding for port 80, is perfectly Ok.

Why do you say that it did not work? Is it because you tried to access your camera, from within the same LAN, but by trying to load your public IP address into your browser?

If this is so, then relax. Many routers (not all) will prevent that, *i.e.*, they block LAN-side requests to their own public IP. Strictly speaking, it might even be your own ISP blocking that, not just you. If this is the first time you try this, then the only way to know for sure you incorrectly configured port-forwarding would be to try from some external location, like your school/office/internet cafè, whatever. If you still cannot get an image, then you are right, there is something else, but until then, you cannot be sure.

If it **is** something else, a list of things to check:

1) you have a modem, and you did not port forward on the modem (there might be no need to do this, but it is surely a point to check);

2) you have a firewall on, perhaps on your modem, and/or your router.

3) Your modem or router has something like *Disallow WAN-side port 80 connections*. This is generally done to prevent people from trying to re-configure your router from outside your LAN, which would compromise your net completely.

4) your pc has a firewall on, which allows LAN-side connections, but forbids WAN-side connections.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best (and best documented) method would be to set up a VPN into your LAN.

If set up correctly (is your PC also your router?), the port forward should work, but it's far less secure (other people can also access your security camera...) - but the interface may depend on more ports than just the one you address. VPN provides a general solution for that (hint - if going to VPN, change your private IP range to a different address - something like 192.168.177.X, or you'll have no luck connecting from anywhere (many, many places) that uses 192.168.1.X

Comment: Well i'd rather access it on android e.t.c, and from different computers. I don't mind others viewing the camera, nothing much sensitive on it. Is there any way for me to be able to access it directly by typing up my public ip in my browser? (I am setting it up for a layman relative)

Comment: Android and other computers can both access VLANs.